# Batch request for youtube playlist_items.delete always failed

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-ruby-client

I have provided "id", but it always return the error that "Required parameter: id"

BTW, if I use normal request (i.e. non-batch), then the same code

```
:api_method => yt.playlist_items.delete,
:parameters => {:id => ids[0]}
```

will success without errors. But if i use batch request, then it always failed!!

Here is my code

```
require 'google/api_client'

client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => 'YouBoard', :application_version => '1.0')
yt = client.discovered_api('youtube', 'v3')
client.authorization.access_token = 'Some Access Token'

response = client.execute!(
  :api_method => yt.playlist_items.list,
  :parameters => {
    :playlistId => pid,
  :part => 'id'
}
)

# Get playlist_item's id
ids = response.data.items.collect {|x| x.id}

batch = Google::APIClient::BatchRequest.new() do |result|
  p result.data
end

batch.add(
 :api_method => yt.playlist_items.delete,
 :parameters => {:id => ids[0]}
)

client.execute!(batch)
```

Here is error

```
"error"=>{"errors"=>[{
"domain"=>"global", 
"reason"=>"required", 
"message"=>"Required parameter: id", 
"locationType"=>"parameter", 
"location"=>"id"}], "code"=>400, "message"=>"Required parameter: id"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in the Google API Ruby client library. I've followed up in the issue tracker for the library: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/issues/detail?id=79